# Making firefox refresh images faster

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, firefox

I have a thing I'm doing where I need a webpage to stream a series of images from the local client computer. I have a very simple run here: http://jsbin.com/idowi/34

The code is extremely simple

```
setTimeout ( "refreshImage()", 100 );

function refreshImage(){
  var date = new Date()
  var ticks = date.getTime()
  $('#image').attr('src','http://127.0.0.1:2723/signature?'+ticks.toString());
  setTimeout ("refreshImage()", 100 );
}
```

Basically I have a signature pad being used on the client machine. We want for the signature to show up in the web page and for them to see themselves signing it within the web page(the pad does not have an LCD to show it to them right there). So I setup a simple local HTTP server which grabs an image of what the current state of the signature pad looks like and it gets sent to the browser.

This has no problems in any browser(tested in IE7, 8, and Chrome) but Firefox where it is extremely laggy and jumpy and doesn't keep with the 10 FPS rate. Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this? I've tried creating very simple double buffering in javascript but that just made things worse.

Also for a bit more information it seems that Firefox is executing the javascript at the correct framerate as on the server the requests are coming in at a constant speed. But the images are only refreshed inconsistently ranging from 5 times per second all the way down to 0 times per second(taking 2 seconds to do a refresh)

Also I have tried using different image formats all with the same results. The formats I've tried include bitmaps, PNGs, and GIFs (GIFs caused a minor problem in Chrome with flicker though)

Could it be possible that Firefox is somehow caching my images causing a slight lag? I send these headers though:

```
Pragma-directive: no-cache
Cache-directive: no-cache
Cache-control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
```

Comment: Sure, don't make it refresh an image every 1/10 of a second... That's outrageous! If you need something to run at 10 FPS, **USE FLASH**!

Comment: @anim there isn't much of an option. it's this or limit ourselves to IE and ActiveX controls. My question is why can every browser handle it but FF. And also without buying expensive Flash licenses(and learning how to use it for this)

Comment: `setTimeout(refreshImage, 100);`  - **don't pass strings to setTimeout()** *please*.

Comment: What do you mean there's not an option? What could it possibly be that you need something to refresh every 1/10 of a second? P.S. It works completely fine for me in FireFox, there's no lag, just a ton and ton of 'images' showing up in my item list.

Comment: I have a wild idea that will probably not work, but I'm suggesting it so some guru out there can start hacking something together.

Take the image that is being generated and convert it to vectors and draw it on the browser using HTML5's `<canvas>` tag.

Comment: @Nick fixed (sorry still a bit new to Javascript) but not the cause of the problem of course.

Comment: @Geek I'm almost for sure that would work worse than this method.

Comment: Not sure what causes the lag, but from my point of view I'd use an interval instead of timeout: `var myInterval = document.setInterval(function() { refreshImage() ; },100) ;`

Comment: @anim Read my question. I explain "what could it possibly be"

Comment: @FK82 yea I had been meaning to change it over to that. Now the weird thing is using `setInterval` actually makes it behave worse. Refresh times approaching 5 seconds

Comment: what is firebug showing?

Comment: @Gutz what do you mean? What am I suppose to look for in Firebug?

Comment: the xhr request to the server, but leakage is nasty.

Comment: @Earlz that's why I prefaced it with "wild idea" and "probably not work" :-). Converting the raster image to vectors will be the highest load - drawing the lines on the canvas from `this point` to the `next point` is easy.

Comment: @ Earlz: Sorry about that. Did you try adding a counter instead of the Date() workaround? `var counter = 0; var refreshImage(counter) = function() { $("#").attr(... + counter.toString() ) ; counter = parseInt(counter) + 100 ; } ; setInterval(function() {refreshImage(counter) ; },100) ;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so turns out this is one of the many leaks of Firefox. I had my firefox session running for days. I restarted it just now and opened up the page and it(and other javascript stuff) ran up to speed. With it being restarted I can now get down to even 50ms refresh rates, though it's not required.

So there isn't really a "fix" to this problem other than to restart firefox every once in a while.

Answer (score 1):

The lag may be caused by the way Firefox handles DNS queries and support for IPv6.

Try [turning off IPv6 lookups](http://thedaneshproject.com/posts/disable-ipv6-in-firefox-3/) and see if that solves the lag.

Comment: The URL he's using have IP addresses (localhost), not names, so no DNS lookup should be involved. (Right?)

Comment: One would hope so, but you never know.  This has solved a lot of "firefox is slow" issues in the past.

Comment: He also says the requests are coming into the server at a constant rate, so it seems like it's not likely to be a network issue.

Comment: Yes and it's also being done on the localhost so there is no network latency

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you've tried this; you said you'd tried "double buffering", but this wouldn't be quite the same. Instead of having one `<img>` tag whose "src" you update, have several (10, maybe). Start them off all "display: none".  Handler the "load" event on the `<img>` tags with a function that hides every other `<img>` except itself. Have your interval timer (which should be an interval timer, probably, and not a series of timeouts like that) iterate through the list of tags, much like it does now.

Will that smooth things out? I'm not sure. I'd certainly try it.

Comment: This would if it was a video or something (probably) but this is real time data. The people are signing a digital signature pad as they are watching these images refresh(it is how they see their own signature being signed) so an extra 200ms between buffers isn't going to help that, infact it will probably make it worse.